# Test Automation - Design for Web/SOA architecture

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

I am finding much about test automation and web architecture using Selenium/java however I'd like to ask about another scenario.

Say you have a text file that contains customer details.  A process then needs to be manually triggered that will parse that file and load the details in a database.  The details are then view-able from a web page.  From the web page you can further add/delete/edit/navigate records.

As a design I was thinking that I would follow this logic:

1. Set-up file and automatically trigger process
2. Automatically parse file and compare with database entries to ensure they were entered correctly.
3. Automatically trigger selenium test to log-in and view results in web page, hence I would have compared the file to the database and the web page to the database.

I am not sure about this approach though, and it provides for various challenges especially in terms of re-initializing state between each test.  Do you think there is a better approach where ultimately I need to make sure that the details in the file end up in the right database tables/columns and that the details can be correctly seen in the web page.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your workflow is adequate, with a small exception.

For state, think about the following from a high level concept of "phases".

Setup Phase:

- Have your automation routine 'create' records for you that you will
  need to use during your automated routines that will follow.
- As the routines create the records for you in DB, it would probably be good
  to have a column with a GUID (36-character) that you can generate.  In other words, do not assume that you will create unique row id 1, row id 2, row id 3 (etc).
- Since you will know this value at create-time, write a manifest file
  to keep track of the DB records you will query during your test run.

Tests Run Phase:

- Run your automated tests, having them utilize the manifest file to
  get their ids necessary. You already mentioned this in "say you have
  a text file that contains customer details".
- With the IDs in the
  manifest, do whatever processes you need to do for test(s).

Teardown:

- Using the manifest file, find your DB records by the identifiers
  (GUIDs) and perform the SQL statements to delete these records.
- Truncate the manifest file so it is now empty (or you can write to it
  in a non-append way for all writes, which will accomplish same goal).